# A mistake in installing gensim

Tags: python, lda, gensim

I can't install gensim successfully through many ways.For I'm  a freshman in coding,it's difficult for me to understand the following information.

---

```
**C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gensim-0.10.3>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <modu
le>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <modu
le>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module>
    from setuptools.compat import numeric_types, basestring
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 19, in <module
>
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in <module>
    class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 208, in SimpleHTTPRequestHand
ler
    mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 358, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 258, in read_windows_registry
    for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 6: ordinal
not in range(128)**
```

---

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to Python I recommend [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), a Python distribution that comes with many useful pacakges (including Gensim, IIRC) ready to use.

Alternatively try

```
pip install Gensim
```

If you don't have pip installed yet look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) answer.